# Is it correct to remove elements with std::list::remove using an alias to an element in the container?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

When I compile this program:

```
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> l = {1, 2};
    l.remove(l.front());
}
```

With clang using ASAN and debug:

```
clang++-8 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -fsanitize=address -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -std=c++11 list-remove.cpp
```

I get a `heap-use-after-free`:

```
==31868==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000020 at pc 0x0000004fa1ae bp 0x7fff52cc5630 sp 0x7fff52cc5628
READ of size 4 at 0x603000000020 thread T0
    #0 0x4fa1ad in std::__debug::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::remove(int const&) /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../../include/c++/7.4.0/debug/list:649:18
    #1 0x4f990f in main /tmp/list-remove.cpp:5:7
    #2 0x7ff27d974b96 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310
    #3 0x41b879 in _start (/tmp/list-remove+0x41b879)
```

It seems when `remove` finds `x` matches the first element, it removes the element from the list and deletes it. When it goes to check the second element, it then uses `x` which has already been deleted to compare the element.

Is this a correct implementation according to C++ standard? It seems it would be better for it to move the elements to the end first and then delete them. This will avoid the `heap-use-after-free` error, but perhaps such an implementation is not required.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) it makes no mention that the `value` cannot be an alias to the element in the container.

Here is the c++ version I am using:

```
$ /usr/bin/c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Did you build with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`?

Comment: Hmm. We don't require `std::remove` to work in such scenarios. I'm not sure why we'd require `list::remove` to, but the wording is missing.

Comment: Looking at the standard as is, it is a bug.  That said, I would assume the usual self referencing rule should apply like it does for `std::remove` and instead the standard has a defect and the code is correct.

Comment: The online draft also doesn't mention that limitation for `std::list`: http://eel.is/c++draft/list#ops-15 Neither does if for `std::remove()` though: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.remove

Comment: @T.C. I can't actually find anything in the standard saying `remove` doesn't have to work when a reference to an element is passed.  Do you know where that is/why cppreference has it in the note?

Comment: @NathanOliver We only require move assignment, so it can't possibly work. This was brought up in the library reflector this April. Responses were...unsympathetic.

Comment: @T.C. It just seems weird that there is no wording one way or the other.  `std::valarray` for instance [handles things like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f05dd2580db3164) without any wording about it.

Comment: @T.C. It seems that libc++ now collects the deleted elements in a separate list and delete them together after all elements are checked.  This way, copy isn't required

Comment: @L.F. For `list::remove`, yes, it's doable. For `std::remove`, no.

Comment: @T.C. Oops, sorry.  I misread your comment somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was asked (and answered) in [LWG 526](https://wg21.link/lwg526), which said:

> `list::remove(value)` is required to work because the standard doesn't give permission for it not to work.

This was fixed in libc++ [back in 2014](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=215210)